# How to fix the error to install the Magento 2.1.5 on live server getting server error 500

Tags: magento

I'm getting the error to install the Magento 2.1.5 and error was a server not found 500? How can I fix the issue and in error log file its show domain name /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php on line 411
syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in

Answer (score 0):

Your var folder does not have the right permissions.

I suggest you follow the official documentation to set the right permissions on your Magento instance: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```